# Strong reference cycle in UITableView

Tags: ios

Suppose I'm using storyboard and I take a TableViewController.The class that I take for writing the code related to that TableViewController is "myTableViewController".Now what happens is that the delegate of UITableView Controller is automatically set in this case and if I want to do the same thing programmatically,I will have to adopt  
protocols and set the current class object as the delegate of UITableViewController.

Now I was reading about strong reference cycles and I'm failing to understand that how the delegate and TableView have references to each other.

If I take a class "Person" and take two member NSString properties "firstName" and "lastName",I can say that the class object will have a strong reference to both NSString objects.But I'm failing to understand this in case of TableView.

Comment: the delegate of a `UITableViewController` has a weak reference, which means that the `UITableViewController` will not be "retaining" the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Objects that are given delegates to use will usually hold weak references to the delegate.  Otherwise (or with older code), you may see cases where you are warned to reset a delegate to nil if the delegate object is being deallocated.

This breaks up cycles.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have some doubts regarding delegates.I have to think over it again and if I face any problems I will ask again.Thanks for now!!!Thanks a lot,this really helped.

Answer (score -1):

Take this code ,for example:

```
@interface myClass<protocols>
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@end
```

Now if I understood correctly,changing the attribute to strong should not cause any problems here because the UITableView delegate property has a reference of type (assign,nonatomic).So it won't create any strong reference cycle here.Am I correct?